# how to add top navigation padding and background colors in share point modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

how to apply colors to  text and background colors of text in spfx[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ram9m.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCIMt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPFX extension to achieve it.

There is a blog about a similar topic for your reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/navigation-bar-in-spfx-with-current-user-greetings2